# how to guess what the interference source it could be

Tags: fourier-transform, radio, interference

At work, we are in an industrial area, and there is always a signal that I receive inside my office which interferences with my tests.

This signal is in the 433 MHz and when I see the spectrum, there are 2 peaks around this center frequency which are shown sort of constantly pulsing, like if someone were pressing a button every 5 seconds (but this is a 24h interference, so it must be something else).

Also, because of the strength of this signal, I wonder if it's something inside my office but we only have routers, wireless phones...I can't think of any wireless device inside my office that could be transmitting at this frequency.

I only can thing about the garage door openers but, as this interference is constantly there, it must be something else.

What sort of device could be doing this?

Comment: *"At work, we are in an industrial area..."*, it might be carrying sensor data or be something entirely custom. Is it possible to post what the spectrum looks like around that frequency?

Comment: I read about it and I found out that it could be our alarm system because the power is high and the transmission is constant so I run the technical support and they confirm, so I guess, problem solved?

Comment: Then, could I please ask you to delete the question if you think that there is no reason to stand anymore, **or**, to self-answer the question and accept it too, so that this question is closed and does not circulate the board as "unanswered"?

Answer (score 1):

I read about it and I found out that it could be our alarm system because the power is high and the transmission is constant so I run the technical support and they confirm, so I guess, problem solved.

However, if someone else had the same issue and found that it was something else, please share :) I read it could be also the thermostat but couldn't find the specs of ours and unless it transmits also when it's not working, I don't think it could be that!